# 0 or 1 is not appearing in the boolean field in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem regarding bit data in mysql when I store a boolean value in the base this value appears 00x

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private boolean inactive;
```

I put this in attribute, but is not working! Comes the same problem.

Comment: `his value appears 00x` ... where are you making this observation?

Comment: yes, in database!

Comment: i would like to know why is it appers in database?

Comment: Don't pay much attention to the DB.  If it works within Java, then it is probably OK.

Comment: Define "is not working".

Comment: 1 or 0 is not appearing in the boolean column in the database but is appearing this value => 0x00

Comment: I am sending a boolean value to the database field but this value 0x00 is coming

Comment: did you understand?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the value stored for true and what is the value stored for false?